# Using metaclass to decorate derived classes to be attr classes

Tags: python, python-attrs

I am currently developing a framework to facilitate writing controller programs for scientific instruments.  I use `attrs` extensively in the internal parts of the code.  I have some parts of the code which exposes classes to be derived from, but I don't want to call `@attr.s` in the beginning whenever I derive a class.  I have an ad-hoc solution, but I would like to know if this decision will give me headaches on the way.

I am using a metaclass when declaring the base class to be further derived from.  I use the `__new__` of the metaclass to decorate the base class.

Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```py
import typing as t
import attr


def setting(
        unit: str = "",
        nicename: t.Optional[str] = None,
        default: t.Optional[t.Any] = None):
    """Returns a setting attribute field to be used in InstrumentSettings
    derived classes.

    Args:
        nicename:  (optional) A unique nice name for referring to the
            setting in texts.
    """

    metadata = dict(
            metatype='setting',
            unit=unit,
            nicename=nicename)
    return attr.ib(metadata=metadata, default=default)



class _InstrumentSettingsMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, supers, attrdict):
        newcls = super().__new__(cls, clsname, supers, attrdict)
        decorated = attr.s(auto_attribs=True)(newcls)

        return decorated

class InstrumentSettings(metaclass=_InstrumentSettingsMeta):
    pass

# Usage
class FooSettings(InstrumentSettings):
    bar: int = setting(default=1)

foosettings = FooSettings()
```

So the above implementation gives the correct behavior as `FooSettings` is perfectly `attrs` decorated.  The thing is that I don't really wanna fiddle with metaclasses because I don't think I fully grok them.  I would appreciate very much if someone could state the downsides & upsides to my approach.  I am also open to other suggestions.

Comment: You might want to look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and see if your question fits there.

Comment: @wwii thank you, I was not aware of that community.  I've posted my question there, should I remove the one here?

Comment: .. someone might still answer here.